# How to convert python list to python dictionary with sequence

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Can somebody tell me how to convert `list1` to `dic_list` with all keys equal to the sequence of elements of the list and all values in dictionary equal to the elements in list split by ','?

---

**input:**

```
list1 = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8']
```

**expected output:**

```
dic_list = {0:['1','2','3'],1:['4','5','6'],2:['7','8']}
```

---

I created a new list2:

```
list2 = []
for num in range(0,len(list1)):
    list2.append(num)

dic_list = dict(zip(list2,list1))
```

But my output is:

```
dic_list = {0:'1,2,3',1:'4,5,6',2:'7,8'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list1 = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8']
final_list = {i:a.split(',') for i, a in enumerate(list1)}
```

Output:

```
{0: ['1', '2', '3'], 1: ['4', '5', '6'], 2: ['7', '8']}
```

Or, using the builting `dict` function:

```
final_list = dict(enumerate(map(lambda x:x.split(','), list1)))
```

Output:

```
{0: ['1', '2', '3'], 1: ['4', '5', '6'], 2: ['7', '8']}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the strings to form lists:

```
list1 = ['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8']

dic_list = {k: v.split(',') for k, v in enumerate(list1)}
dic_list
```

#### output:

```
{0: ['1', '2', '3'], 1: ['4', '5', '6'], 2: ['7', '8']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate to get the key and split the list with ',' to get desired value.

```
list1 = ['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8']
Output = {key: value.split(',') for key, value in enumerate(list1)} 
Output
```